# Cross-chain Hydra

Tags: plutus

Been thinking about the Taproot upgrade and what it means for bundling validation into Bitcoin transactions. While Hydra requires three validation scripts in Plutus, the similiarities between EUTxO and UTxO would suggest that there is another validator architecture that would create a compatible isomorphic state channel on Bitcoin. Is this feasible and what sort of hurdles have to be overcome?